# How do I extract a floating number in the middle of an alphanumeric chain?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am coding in Fortran 95.

I must extract the two floating values from this line in an ascii file:

```
circle(4097.0438,4111.337)
```

Of course the READ statement is

```
read(unit=11, fmt="(tr7,f9.4,tr1,f8.3)") x, y
```

The problem is that I must do that for hundreds of ascii files, but there are variations in the number of digits. For instance:

```
circle(201.043,7250.1234) # which would require fmt="(tr7,f7.3,tr1,f9.4)"

circle(0.004038,9999.12) # which would require fmt="(tr7,f8.6,tr1,f7.2)"

circle(0.004038,22.1234) # etc
```

Therefore I cannot use a single format. I don't know how to read those x, y coordinates using free format because I must skip the first 7 spaces anyway.

Comment: By "Fortran 95" do you mean that you cannot use anything from later standards, TRs (F2003, F2008, etc.)?  Either way, adding the generic [tag:fortran] would enhance this question's visibility.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks! +1 (but I am restricted to fortran 95)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading in the data into a string buffer and removing unnecessary parts probably work.

```
program main
    character(100) :: buf
    real :: x, y

    read( *, "(a)" ) buf
    buf = buf( 8 : len(trim(buf))-1 ) !! remove "circle(" and ")"
    read( buf, * ) x, y               !! read two reals (commas/spaces are regarded as separators)
    print *, x, y
end
```

Another way is to use index() to find "(" and ") [please see [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485531/how-to-read-comma-delimited-data-file-if-some-data-include-spaces) also]. In this case the data may contain any string before "(" or after ")". Similar methods can be used to extract necessary parts in more complicated cases.

```
integer :: n1, n2
n1 = index( buf, "(" )
n2 = index( buf, ")" )
read( buf( n1+1 : n2-1 ), * ) x, y
```

Comment: You can also use `len_trim(..)` instead of `len(trim(..))`.

Comment: @francescalus thank you, then I will remove my comment above later. Btw, is this "len_trim()"  a function in fortran2008?

Comment: @francescalus hmm... pretty old. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LEN_005fTRIM.html

Answer (score 2):

To supplement [roygvib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856061) I'll add a "cute" something.  This takes the suggested approach of using list-directed input from an internal file.

```
program main
  character(100) :: buf
  complex :: temp
  real :: x, y

  read( *, "(a)" ) buf
  read(buf(7:), *, decimal='point') temp ! read a complex
  x = temp%RE                            ! assign x as real part of that
  y = temp%IM                            ! assign y as imaginary part

  print *, x, y
end
```

[Instead of `temp%RE`, `temp%IM`, possibly `REAL(temp)`, `AIMAG(temp)`.]

This works because we know that for a complex number with list-directed input (Fortran 2008, 10.10.3)

> the input form consists of a left parenthesis followed by an ordered pair of numeric input fields separated by a comma (if the decimal edit mode is POINT) or semicolon (if the decimal edit mode is COMMA), and followed by a right parenthesis.

I made the `decimal='point'` explicit in the code above.  I also didn't remove the prefix from the buffer character variable itself.

Yes, this offers very little except less worry about removing the parantheses.

Comment: I choosed the other answer because I can only choose one and also it was slightly more straightforward (I happen to have used lists very little). But I am very thankful for your answer, I am going to study it so that I learn about lists.

Comment: The other answer is much more worthy of being accepted.  It gives the real detail, this is just a more fun addition applicable because of one very specific aspect.

Comment: By "list-directed" I mean what you call "free format".  That is, the `*` rather than explicit format.  Not really related to lists.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it is very interesting. Taking advantage of such specific aspects sometimes is the funniest part of coding.